# Are the privacy controls only for Unity?

Tags: unity

Sorry for my ignorance, I am new to Linux. I've read on the web, that Unity spied and sent some data for "statistics" and such. Also I've read the privacy controls won't be in 13.04. So what I am wondering about is - Does Ubuntu 13.04(with Unity) sends your data somewhere for "whatsoever reason"? And if yes, what about the alternative desktops(Lubuntu,Xubuntu,etc.)

Comment: It helps if you could link to where you read about these privacy issues so peopel can respond to them.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 13.04 does include Privacy controls, and no, the other Desktop Environments do not send your data anywhere.

Unity sends only searches (anonymously) to a server which only takes care of online searches (such as Amazon and Videos).